# Way to shift bytes to right in the byte array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a huge array, what I need is the ability to shift the array on the custom length of bytes to the right and the position from where to shift should be custom as well, for example:

```
Dim data() As Byte = {0, 128, 0, 4, 9, 9, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

I want to shift the fourth element in 4 bytes and fill it with zeros(so it looks like insert bytes in the array):

```
  Dim data() As Byte = {0, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 9, 9, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

What have i tried:

```
            Dim data(200) As Byte
            Dim data_shifted(400) As Byte
            For b As Integer = 200 To 3 Step -1
                data(b) = data_shifted(b - 3)
            Next
```

this is not fit me, because it can shift only first bytes, i can't choose the custom array position
I was looking to the **Stack.Push()** but can't figure out how to use it here

Comment: You might want to consider using a `System.ArraySegment(Of Byte)` to provide an adjustable window to an arbitrary segment of the array without having to move the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Array.Copy(data, beginAtIndx, data_shifted, beginAtIndxShift, shiftLength)
```

The three arguments(other than the arrays) all represent Integer variables

Comment: the problem is that it's overwriting the values, I need it to  shift existing arrays in order to not lose it,